# Merge multiple excel sheet to one sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an xls file which containes multiple sheets, i want to merge all this sheet in one and only one sheet.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os 
import xlrd

df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_excel, glob.glob(os.path.join('', "bank.xls"))))
```

Tried this got a warning

```
WARNING *** file size (25526815) not 512 + multiple of sector size (512)
```

And nothing Happened

[I want to concat all this sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNqED.png)

Comment: Do you mean you want to merge the four spreadsheets contents into a single content spreadsheet?

Comment: Are you trying to `merge` or `append`?

Comment: @Chris Merge i think

Comment: @FranJ i want to merge all this sheet https://i.imgur.com/XwA37bg.png

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-excel/6Lue-1mTPSM

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (just tested).

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
input_file = 'C:\\your_path\\Book1.xlsx'
output_file = 'C:\\your_path\\BookFinal.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(input_file, None)
all_df = []
for key in df.keys():
    all_df.append(df[key])
data_concatenated = pd.concat(all_df,axis=0,ignore_index=True)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_file)
data_concatenated.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='merged',index=False)
writer.save()
```